Clang-format configuration file: what happens if a parameter was not mentioned
Assuming I don't want to learn all the parameters available for сustomization in .clang-format config file, but I'd like to specify only a few ones and not to describe the rest. How clang-format tool can react on incomplete .clang-format file: just ignores the params which were not mentioned or applies missed settings by default, using llvm style?
For example, I have a piece of unformatted code:
void testFunction (uint8_t num) {
        int val1=0;
  float val2 = 1;
      short val3 = 2;
    switch(num) {
    case 1: {
    val3=val1+val2;
    }break;
    }
    
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<num;i++){
        if(i==num/2) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

In order to test clang-format I firstly generated .clang-format, using Microsoft style, then, I commented all the lines, which refer to line alignment (like AlignXXX). The expectation was: nothing alignments in the piece of code should have happened. The result:
void testFunction(uint8_t num) {
  int val1 = 0;
  float val2 = 1;
  short val3 = 2;
  switch (num){
  case 1: {
    val3 = val1 + val2;
  } break;
  }

  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    if (i == num / 2) {
      break;
    }
  }
}

So, it can be noticed, that at least all the initializations have been formatted(int val1 = 0 etc), but they should have stayed as is.
